# CQRS/ES AR deletion command

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

Let's say I've an event sourced blog engine application in  which I can create, publish and un-publish posts... I'm now wondering how to implement the post deletion command. Should I create a post deletion event, store it in the event store, and then, listen to that event to remove the projection, or should I fully delete the post, including any related events from the event store? The problem with the second solution is that I wouldn't be able to rolling back the deletion and I'm pretty sure that removing events from the events store is a really bad practice with event sourced applications.

Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in a domain where you are using event sourcing, presumably because there is business value in temporal queries, then you are probably going to want soft deletes, rather than actually destroying the history you have accumulated.

See also: [Don't Delete -- Just Don't](http://udidahan.com/2009/09/01/dont-delete-just-dont/).

Comment: Good morning, Yes, so basically put, I shouldn't remove the associated events (the history), but of course, I still need to remove the projection, right? Removing the projection (read model) shouldn't pose any problem I think, right? I could just have a PostWasDeleted event for soft deletion and a listener listening on that event responsible to remove the projection, right? Another way of course would be to project the soft deletion (status field) and ignore such AR when querying the read model but  why should I do that? The history should make me able to rollback if really needed, isn't it?

Comment: You can remove a record from the read model  if your app never need it. 
Or you can just mark record as 'deleted' and filter out such records in normal use. This way it will be easier to 'undelete' these records if you need them.